# Compiling Novell.Directory.LDAP with the error code resources intact

Tags: android, mono, ldap, xamarin

Novell's LDAP library is included as part of the Mono project, but it isn't available when building MonoDroid projects because the base libraries don't match (so it's not offered as a library Reference option).

So I complied it directly from the Mono source as an Android library, but I can't get the resources to be included because they are in resx files and making that work in Mono seems really hit-and-miss. Without the resources, the error messages don't work.

I know it's possible because @jonathanpeppers has achieved it in [these binaries](https://github.com/xamarin/prebuilt-apps/tree/master/EmployeeDirectory/Dependencies/Novell.Directory.Ldap), but they have [this bug](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=436775), which I would like to fix and recompile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go back in the history for the project, you can see the source file used to be included directly in. https://github.com/xamarin/prebuilt-apps/commit/0f8784ebc272f72d9398897b4e54eef8965af7a9

Most libraries can easily be recompiled from source!

Comment: While this didn't work out of the box, it did give me a good steer. I needed to change the _Build action_ of the two .resx files to **EmbeddedResource** and make sure the _Resource ID_ property didn't contain any namespace info so the runtime lookup would work.